# Oracle imp and exp commands

Tags: oracle, unix, sqlplus, exp, imp

Normally when i have to take a backup of of a database on unix, i do,

```
exp DBUSER/DBPSW@INST file=xxx.dmp
```

or load from a dump

```
imp DBUSER/DBPSW@INST file=xxx.dmp
```

my question here is :

1. how can we take a backup of a single
   table
2. how can we import the data backup
   from the dump into a single table.
3. how can we disable the constraints
   when taking a backup

I rarely do these when required.some times i need to do the above mentioned things but instead because i donot know i take the complete backup of all the table and load it.
does anybody know how we can do it?

Comment: This may just be a problem of terminology, but `imp` and `exp` are utilities for transporting database objects and data, they are not intended to be part of a backup strategy. `RMAN` is the appropriate tool to use for backups.

Comment: Not an answer to your question but : switch to expdp and impdp.

Answer (score 3):

You can list tables you want to export or import in your command line as 'tables=...'
Or run exp/imp interactively and it will ask you for list of tables. Here is a good 
[FAQ](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/Import_Export_FAQ)